# Are the orbits of this discrete dynamical system bounded?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Is this a known result? If no such result (or similar result) is known, a proof or counterexample will suffice.

**Concise Version**

> **Conjecture:** Let $f\colon \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ be a function.
> Assume that for some index set $I$, there are $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\Bbb Z$ such that
>
> - $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(a_i+b_i\Bbb N_0)$ and $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(c_i+d_i\Bbb N_0)$
> - For all $i\in I$, $n\in\Bbb N_0$, we have $f(a_i+b_in)=c_i+d_in$
> - For all $i\in I$, we have $a_ib_i\ge 0$ and $c_id_i\ge 0$
> - For all $i\in I$, if $b_i\ne d_i$, then $\frac{a_i-c_i}{b_i-d_i}>0$
> - For all $i\in I$, the set $\{\,f^{\circ k}(a_i)\mid k\in\Bbb N_0\,\}$ is finite
>
> Then for all $x\in \Bbb Z$, the set $\{\,f^{\circ k}(x)\mid k\in\Bbb N_0\,\}$ is finite.

**Descriptive Version**

> - Given an iterative piecewise linear function, $f$, with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ and range $\mathbb{Z}$ :
> - under iteration by $f$, if the trajectories/iterates of the first integers in all the subdomains converge to a cycle;
> - then, the trajectories of all integers in the domain of $f$ will converge to a cycle, that is, no trajectory diverges.
>   -**Special Conditions:** (1) Zero can be included or excluded from $f$. (2) It is assumed that the subdomains and subranges are in arithmetic progression containing non-negative or non-positive integers but not a mix. (3) It is also assumed that if $f$ has only two subfunctions then the cycle must be of length 1 and, of course, $f(x)\neq x$ unless $x$ is the element to which all the trajectories of the first elements converge. (4) Importantly, if one element in a subdomain is greater than its corresponding element in the subrange, then all elements in that subdomain must be greater than  their corresponding elements in the subrange. The same is true if one element in a subdomain is less than its corresponding element in the subrange.

$\color{black}{\text{Example 1}}$

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{subdoman: 1, 3, 5, 7,...Subrange: 2, 4, 6, 8,...} \\
-x+2, & \text{subdoman: 2, 4, 6, 8,...Subrange: 0,-2,-4,-6...}\\
-x, & \text{subdoman: -1, -3, -5,...Subrange: 1, 3, 5, ...}\\
x+1, & \text{subdoman: -2, -4, -6,...Subrange: -1, -3, -5,...}\\
0, & \text{subdoman: 0 $\hspace{1.6cm}$ Subrange: 0}
\end{cases}$$
Note that the trajectories of the first elements $(1, 2, -1$ and $-2)$ of the subdomains all converge to $0$ implying that no trajectory will diverge.
For example, the trajectory of $6$ under $f$ is: $6\to-4 \to-3\to3\to4\to-2\to-1\to1\to2\to0.$

$\color{black}{\text{Example 2}}$

Here is a second example in which the first elements of the subdomains converge to the cycle $-1, 1$ and $0$ is excluded:
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x,  & \text{subdoman:2, 4, 6, 8,...Subrange: 3, 6, 9, 12...} \\
\frac{-3}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:1, 3, 5, 7,...Subrange:-1,-4,-7, -10...}\\
\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:-1, -3, -5,...Subrange:1, 2, 3, ...}\\
\frac{1}{2}x, & \text{subdoman:-2, -4, -6,...Subrange:-1, -2, -3,...}
\end{cases}$$
In this example, the trajectory of 6 is $6\to9\to-13\to7\to-10\to-5\to3\to-4\to-2\to-1\to1.$

Comment: How about this for a counterexample:  $f(x) = 2x$ if $x$ is positive and even, $f(x) = x-1$ if $x$ is positive and odd, and $f(x) = 1-x$ if $x$ is not positive.  The only cycle is $1 \to 2 \to 1$, and $0$ and $-1$ map into this cycle, but all other trajectories diverge to $+\infty$.

Comment: "the first element in the sub-domains of all the sub-functions all converge...." What does this mean? What's a "sub-function"? What a "sub-domain" of a "sub-function"? What's the "first element" in a "sub-domain"? And how can an element converge to anything? A sequence might converge to something, a series might converge to something, but how can an element converge?

Comment: Since I'm not sure whether my example fits the spirit of your last rule (if there are only two sub-functions, then the cycle has length 1), here's a method by which you can construct more counterexamples:  pick some sub-domains for your linear functions (e.g. positive evens, positive odds, negative evens, negative odds), and choose a fixed point (let's say 0).  On each subdomain, define $f$ by a rapidly increasing function that sends the first possible input to 0 and otherwise satisfies $|f(x)| > |x|$.  E.g. for positive evens you could use $f(x) = 100(x-2)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I assume "sub-functions" means the linear functions defining $f$, "sub-domains" refers to the partition of $\mathbb Z$ on which $f$ is defined by these linear functions, "first element" means the element in a sub-domain (which we require to be an arithmetic progression in $\mathbb Z^+$ or $\mathbb Z^-$, or the singleton $\{0\}$) with smallest absolute value, and an element "converges" somewhere if its trajectory (i.e. the sequence $n, f(n), f(f(n)), \dots$) converges there.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thanks for clarifying the terminologies. Your first example fails as the first element of the domain of the subfunction $f(x)=1-x$ is $-1$ which diverges, that is, $-1\to2\to4\to8...$. For your second example, choosing a fixed point then sending $f$ rapidly increasing makes it difficult to ensure the range of $f$ is the set of $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, having a subfunction $f(x) = 100(x-2)$ if $x$ is positive and even means the subrange here will be 0, 200, 400, ... Did I miss something?

Comment: @Math777 Sorry, I mistyped the cases in my example.  It should be:  $f(x) = 2x$ if $x$ is positive and *odd*, $f(x) = x - 1$ if $x$ is positive and *even*, and $f(x) = 1 - x$ if $x$ is not positive.

Comment: As for your second objection, I hadn't realized that you meant to require the function to be surjective (i.e. range = $\mathbb Z$, not just codomain).  My examples are not surjective.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384320/looking-for-a-reference-proof-or-counterexample-to-this-claim

Comment: Say we take $g$ to be
$$ g(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{x}{2},  & \text{subdomain: 2, 4, 6, 8,...} \\
\frac{-3x+1}{2}, & \text{subdomain: 1, 3, 5, 7,...}\\
\frac{-3x-1}{2}, & \text{subdomain: -1, -3, -5,...}\\
-\frac{x}{2}, & \text{subdomain: -2, -4, -6,...}
\end{cases} $$
Following your terminology, all four first elements converge to the $-1,1$ cycle. and we also have $$7 \rightarrow -10 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow -7 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow -5 \rightarrow7$$
However I do not see how this cycle is a "permutation of parts of the trajectories of the first elements".

Comment: @user3733558 I'll remove that thought. Thanks for the added example.